# Which version does glGetString(GL_VERSION) get?

Tags: opengl

Does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` get the maximum supported version for your system, or the version for your current context?

I know that you need to create a context in order for `glGetString()` to work, so that is what made me wonder if it was the current context or the highest available.

Comment: The "current context" is an operation-system context.  What operating system are you trying this on?

Comment: Right now I am working on Windows 8.1, but will eventually move to OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the spec (copied from 3.3 spec document):

> String queries return pointers to UTF-8 encoded, NULL-terminated static strings describing properties of the current GL context.

So it's the version supported by the current context. There's a subtle aspect if you're operating in a client/server setup:

> GetString returns the version number (in the VERSION string) that can be supported by the current GL context. Thus, if the client and server support different versions a compatible version is returned.

The way I read this, it will return the minimum between the client and server if the two versions are different.

It's generally easier to use `glGetIntegerv()` to check the version. This way, you don't have to start parsing strings, and you can also get additional detail:

```
GLint majVers = 0, minVers = 0, profile = 0, flags = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &majVers);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minVers);
glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &profile);
glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);

if (profile & GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT) {
    ...
}

if (profile & GL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT) {
    ...
}

if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current context, it is a valid way to query what context you're currently rendering under.

See:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetString

> glGetString: return a string describing the current GL connection